# Use of modifier static in c

Tags: c

I'm a beginner learning c. I know that use of word "static" makes a c function and variable local to the source file it's declared in. But consider the following...

test.h

```
static int n = 2;
static void f(){
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"
int main()
{
    printf("%d", n);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

My expected result was that an error message will throw up, since the function f and variable n is local to test.h only? Thanks.

But instead, the output was

```
2
2
```

EDIT:
If it only works for a compilation unit, what does that mean? And how do I use static the way I intended to?

Comment: ...makes a C function and variable local to the _compilation unit_ (not any "file") it's declared in

Comment: One of the reasons why you should't put code and variables in .h files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static` makes your function/variable local to the *compilation unit*, ie the whole set of source code that is read when you compile a single `.c` file.

`#include`ing a `.h` file is a bit like copy/paste-ing the content of this header file in your `.c` file. Thus, `n` and `f` in your example are considered local to your `main.c` compilation unit.

### Example

#### `module.h`

```
#ifndef MODULE_H
#define MODULE_H

int fnct(void);

#endif /* MODULE_H */
```

#### `module.c`

```
#include "module.h"

static
int
detail(void)
{
  return 2;
}

int
fnct(void)
{
  return 3+detail();
}
```

#### `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module.h"

int
main(void)
{
  printf("fnct() gives %d\n", fnct());
  /* printf("detail() gives %d\n", detail()); */
  /* detail cannot be called because:
     . it was not declared
       (rejected at compilation, or at least a warning)
     . even if it were, it is static to the module.c compilation unit
       (rejected at link)
  */
  return 0;
}
```

build (compile each `.c` then link)

```
gcc -c module.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o prog module.o main.o
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just read The C Programming Language by K&R, on p83, the book reads "The static declaration, applied to an external variable or function, limits the scope of that object to rest of the source file...". I guess I was confused by the non-plural...

Comment: It's also about lifetime, if you have a static variable it's value will persist between function calls until the program ends

Comment: @Kevin Glasson Yes, it's so confusing that the same keyword is used with different meanings, depending on the context... (and there is a third meaning in C++!!!)

Answer (score 1):

You have included `test.h` in `main.c`.

Therefore `static int n` and `static void f()` will be visible inside `main.c` also.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable or function is declared at *file scope* (not inside any other `{ }` brace pair), and they are declared `static`, they are local to the *translation unit* they reside in.

*Translation unit* is a formal term in C and it's slightly different from a file. A translation unit is a single c file and all the h files it includes.

So in your case, the `static` variable is local to the translation unit consisting of `test.h` and `main.c`. You will be able to access it in main.c, but not in foo.c.

Meaning that if you have another .c file including `test.h`, you'll get two instances of the same variable, with the same name. That in turn can lead to all manner of crazy bugs.

This is one of many reasons why we ***never*** define variables inside header files.

(To avoid spaghetti program design, we should not declare variables in headers either, unless they are `const` qualified.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Neither. I've clarified this.